# Vuetify v-data-table v-if issue

Tags: vuetify.js

Alright, so I have a `v-data-table` with one column that conditionally shows either a `checkmark` icon or an `x` icon :

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" item-key="id">
    <template v-slot:headers="props">
        <tr>
            <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">{{ header.text }}</th>
        </tr>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:items="props">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <v-icon v-if="props.item.status === 1" color="light-green">fas fa-check</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-if="props.item.status === 0" color="red">fas fa-times</v-icon>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

**The issue is:** While paginating the data in this table, rows where `v-if` evaluate differently stay rendered, as in they don't go away, and more icons are actually appended rather than replacing what's there.

So say on Page 1, the third row has a status of `0`, so it renders an `x`, then on Page 2, the third row has a status of `1`, but instead of showing `checkmark`, it shows `x checkmark`. Then I switch back to Page 1, and it shows `x checkmark` still... then when I go back to Page 2, it shows `x checkmark checkmark`, and so on as many times as I switch back and forth.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I've tried instead using `v-show`, but this one also acts weirdly - it only renders the result of the first page, and doesn't change when switching pages. I guess also considered a bug.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYarza?&editable=true&editors=101) I made that doesn't seem to have any issues

Comment: Thanks for sharing that - I put all of the layers, parent components etc in codepen, and it worked >_< still not working in my project though. Same version of vuetify, 2.5.17 for vue, tried updating to 2.6.10 like what's in codepen but same result. Gonna have to dig deeper... -.-

Comment: what do you have in your project that you don't have in the codepen?

Comment: @depperm see answer, fa icon to svg conversion

Answer (score 1):

Oh bother. In the project there's a utility that converts FA icons into SVG, and by doing so it overrides the default behavior of v-data-table. Switched to Material icons, works fine.